# React native pure js module with flow

Tags: react-native, npm, flowtype, expo

I'm trying to publish my first react native pure js module which uses flow. I'm having a hard time.

My repo is here - https://github.com/Noitidart/react-native-buttonex

Source is in `./src/index.js`. I use flow there. So I have done in my repo `npm i flow-bin@0.57.3 --save-dev`.

I then simply did a `npm publish`. Is there anything else I need to do?

It is not able to be used in Expo.

Doing:

```
import Button from 'react-native-buttonex' // ERROR. The Expo team has been notified.
```

Adds that "Error: expo team has been notified". And trying to run it shows red box with "Failed to download module".

I thought to stip the flowtypes so I added `.babelrc` with:

```
{
    "presets": ["flow"]
}
```

But when I run babel I get error:

```
SyntaxError: src/index.js: Unexpected token (29:10)
  27 |
  28 | class Button extends Component<Props, State> {
> 29 |     state = {
     |           ^
  30 |         activeAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
  31 |     }
```

It seems like its not liking the ES2017 stuff which is normal for react-native.
May you please guide m on how to properly publish this?

Comment: May be you would want to declare state inside the constructor? `this.state = {...}`

Comment: @NanduKalidindi - I don't want to change my code, as if I copied and pasted this into any RN project it would work. So it must mean I am doing something else wrong. I think all I need it to do is strip flow.

Comment: I think you want to get this one: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/